# Clojure iterate a vector and look ahead/look behing

Tags: dictionary, clojure, iteration

I do have to iterate over a vector, which in turn has maps as its items. I need to compare which map comes next, and sometimes I need to look what was in the map we looked at before. So it is necessary to have some kind of look ahead/look behind functionality. My current approach works, but I guess it is ugly, unidiomatic Clojure and I assume that there must be a better (more canonical) way to achieve this.

```
(let [result (apply str (map (fn [{position-before :position compound-before :compund } ; previous term (unfortunately we need to compare all three)
                                        {:keys [word position line tag stem compound grammarpos] :or {grammarpos "0" stem "" } } ; this maps to the current word
                                        {position-ahead :position compound-ahead :compound line-ahead :line}] ; this is for lookahead
                (do some stuff)) ;; now we have position, which is our current position, position-before and position-after to compare with each other
                ;; this is how we map:
                (into  '[{}] (conj grammar '[{}]))
                (next (into  '[{}] (conj grammar '[{}])))
                (next (next (into  '[{}] (conj grammar '[{}]))))))])
```

As for the request of the data-example, this is a part of the vector:

```
[{:tag "0", :position "0", :line "0", :stem "dev", :grammarpos "2625", :word "deva"} {:tag "0", :position "0", :line "0", :stem "deva", :grammarpos "4", :word "deva"}]
```

The job is to compare values for position, compound etc., sometimes look ahead, sometimes look behind.

Comment: Could you add a small/representative data set to your question?  If you could show what is in your vector of maps and what you want to return from it, you might attract more explicit help.

Comment: Added them, hope it serves to clarify the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could iterate over a `partition` of your vector, with a size of 3 and step of 1. Then for each element in the vector, you also get the before and after that you can study as you iterate with a `for` or `reduce`.

Some examples: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/partition

Answer (score 3):

also if you need all the preceding and following items for every item, you can combine `for` list comprehension, with destructuring.

for example:

```
user> (def items [:a :b :c :d :e :f :g])
#'user/items

user> (for [index (range (count items))
            :let [[before [current & after]] (split-at index items)]]
        {:before before :current current :after after})

({:before (), :current :a, :after (:b :c :d :e :f :g)} 
 {:before (:a), :current :b, :after (:c :d :e :f :g)} 
 {:before (:a :b), :current :c, :after (:d :e :f :g)} 
 {:before (:a :b :c), :current :d, :after (:e :f :g)} 
 {:before (:a :b :c :d), :current :e, :after (:f :g)} 
 {:before (:a :b :c :d :e), :current :f, :after (:g)} 
 {:before (:a :b :c :d :e :f), :current :g, :after nil})
```

you just split collection at every item's index one by one, and from the result take first item (before), first of second item (current), rest of second item (after)

also a bit less readable way (but probably more productive for big collection, since it doesn't do `take`/`drop` on every step, but adds/removes a single item to coll)

```
user> (take (count items)
            (iterate
             (fn [[before current after]]
               [(conj before current) (first after) (rest after)])
             [[] (first items) (rest items)]))

([[] :a (:b :c :d :e :f :g)] 
 [[:a] :b (:c :d :e :f :g)] 
 [[:a :b] :c (:d :e :f :g)] 
 [[:a :b :c] :d (:e :f :g)] 
 [[:a :b :c :d] :e (:f :g)] 
 [[:a :b :c :d :e] :f (:g)] 
 [[:a :b :c :d :e :f] :g ()])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do really complex things, perhaps [zippers](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.zip-api.html#clojure.zip/zipper) will be a better solution.

For example, lets say that you start with:

```
(def x
  [{:tag "0" :dups 0}
   {:tag "1" :dups 0}
   {:tag "1" :dups 0}
   {:tag "3" :dups 0}])
```

And your requirements are to increment the dups counter of all consecutive tags with the same name and add a "---" tag between them.

With zippers the solution will look like:

```
(require '[clojure.zip :as zip :refer [root node]])

(defn complex-thing [zip]
  (if (zip/end? zip) ;; are we done?
    (root zip) ;; return the "updated" vector
    (let [current-node (node zip)
          before-node (node (zip/prev zip))] ;; you can access any map in the vector, both before or after
      (if (= (:tag current-node) (:tag before-node))
        (recur (-> zip
                   zip/prev ;; move to the previous map
                   (zip/edit update :dups inc) ;; increment it
                   zip/next ;; move back to the current map
                   (zip/edit update :dups inc)
                   (zip/insert-left {:tag "----"}) ;; insert "---" before the current tag
                   zip/next)) ;; move to next map to process
        (recur (zip/next zip))))))

(complex-thing (zip/next (zip/next (zip/vector-zip x)))) ;; start from the second element of the vector

[{:tag "0", :dups 0} 
 {:tag "1", :dups 1} 
 {:tag "----"} 
 {:tag "1", :dups 1} 
 {:tag "3", :dups 0}]
```